# Is this a standard type of graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I have some nodes linked together in this graph fashion. The top node has a left and a right "child", but as you can see, when you go a level further, left and right children share common children and this pattern continues. The question is, is this a standard type of graph?

[image]

Comment: This graph is an example of a [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)).

Answer (score 1):

One might think of it as a truncated [dependency graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph) for [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle):

[image: Pascal's Triangle]

Answer (score 0):

It is the product of two path graphs (which forms a checkerboard shape), cut in half diagonally.

Comment: Specifically, the Cartesian product.